# Java 11 on latest Mac OS seems to lock the file system for minutes at a time

Tags: java, macos, java-11

Since upgrading to java 11 on my Macbook Pro (latest OS, etc.) compiling projects seems to often lock the entire file system for long periods of time. Anyone else having this problem? Any ideas how to debug it?

Update: I did a `dtruss` on the process and I see endless output like this. I don't know if this is significant or not.

```
gettimeofday(0x700001D00D98, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
gettimeofday(0x7000011DCE18, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
psynch_cvwait(0x7F8EF6417C10, 0x89A0100089B00, 0x0)      = -1 316
gettimeofday(0x700001D00D98, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
psynch_cvwait(0x7F8EF6417C10, 0x89B0100089C00, 0x0)      = -1 316
gettimeofday(0x700001D00D98, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
psynch_cvwait(0x7F8EF6417C10, 0x89C0100089D00, 0x0)      = -1 316
gettimeofday(0x700001D00D98, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
psynch_cvwait(0x7F8EF6417C10, 0x89D0100089E00, 0x0)      = -1 316
gettimeofday(0x700001D00D98, 0x0, 0x0)       = 0 0
psynch_cvwait(0x7F8EF6417C10, 0x89E0100089F00, 0x0)      = -1 316
```

Just endless calls to that and then every once in a while:

```
stat64("<xxxx>.class\0", 0x700000CCBF30, 0x0)        = 0 0
lstat64("<xxxx>.class\0", 0x700000CCBDE8, 0x0)       = 0 0
```

Update: well, it's in the bug db now: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8257477

Comment: My current theory is that this is related to Spotlight. My console is filled with Spotlight crashes:

Oct  4 14:34:01 com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.apple.mdworker.shared.1A000000-0600-0000-0000-000000000000[32709]): Service exited due to SIGKILL | sent by mds[184]
etc

Comment: discussions.apple.com is literally full of thread with these Spotlight errors:

* [system.log is full of repeated log messages post-upgrade to 10.15.5](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251403759)
* [Continuous 'Service Exited in system log](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251433748)
* [Frequent Kernel Panic](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251453282)

Comment: I no longer think it's Spotlight. I disabled Spotlight and it still happens. I've tried with JDK 15 and the latest 16 EA build. A jstack dump when it happens always shows a thread running at "at sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.unlink0(java.base@15/Native Method)" - don't know if this is the culprit.

Comment: What do you mean lock the entire file system? If you try to create or delete a file, you can’t?

Comment: tbh when I say "lock entire file system" it's a bit of a guess. What I mean is that it appears that any Mac process trying to access the file system hangs - Finder, Mail, etc. This doesn't always happen; only in the worst instances maybe 5-10% of the time.

Comment: FYI - here are two stack traces. Maven build: https://gist.github.com/Randgalt/be4d53c6d9306b9f5f8d7de85ca66e0f - IntelliJ build:
https://gist.github.com/Randgalt/492fefdeb913e177c5b12e20867b9f49

Comment: I’ve been running Java 11 on my MBP for a long time, and recently upgraded to Big Sur. I’ve not experienced any noticeable slowness before or after. Have you tried the usuals, reinstalling Java, and also a system restore? Those usually work wonders for Windows, but you may be surprised.

Comment: FYI - the _release_ of JDK 11 works fine (11.0.9)! I'm wondering if there is some kind of debug code in these EA builds? Also, FYI, I opened a bug report with Oracle though that probably won't have much luck.

Comment: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/x/noHfCw. Note 251642 and 251468.

Comment: Oracle won’t do anything with a problem in an EA build that doesn’t exist in the GA. Also note that Java 11 is now more than 2 year old.